# Moving out of bundled Javascript during local debugging

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp

Current tasks on **gulpfile.js** on my frontend app included a `serve` task on which it did the following:

- Processed less files
- Bundled all javascripts into dist/bundle.js
- Uglified dist/bundle.js

Since that made things hard for local debugging, I've created a new `serve:debug` task that, at first, did not uglified `dist/bundle.js`.

```
gulp.task('serve:debug', ['less', 'bundle', 'watch'], function () {
    runServer('http://localhost/app/login.html')
});
```

That works and makes me able to at least debug human readable javascript code. But all files are still bundled together because my application explicitly imports `dist/bundle.js` on index.html:

```
<script src="dist/bundle.js"></script>
```

If I remove `bundle` task on `serve:debug`, application will not be able work reach `dist/bundle.js` anymore.

**Question:** What are the best practices to work around this when importing javascript files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`gulp-sourcemaps`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sourcemaps) to write an inline sourcemap into your bundle.  This will cause the browser's developer tools to display source as if it were in the original source files despite actually being served in a bundle.

This would look something like:

```
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

gulp.task('bundle', function() {
  gulp.src('src/**/*.js')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
      .pipe(bundle())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

There's a good general overview of how source maps work here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/

Comment: Cool! Could you include a sample of how would that look?

Comment: And that would work just like magic? Do you know anything on the internals of that?

Comment: I haven't looked at the internals, but it's not magic. :) It just writes a comment that starts with `//# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;base64` to the end of the file.

Comment: Thanks for the link... Is there any concerns on using this config for the production build as well? Or should I stick with this only for the dev build?

Comment: It's really a judgement call.  It adds some bytes (page weight) and exposes your original source (comments and all) to anyone who wants to look.  If you're cool with that, then the benefit is being able to more easily debug issues in production.

Comment: Thanks! I'll leave this up to the right folks to decide whether to leave that on on prod, but this solves my debugging problem on dev perfectly.